# When to use " " and ' ' in a sentence

Tags: american-english, british-english, quotations

I was in a dilemma when to use " " (double quotes) and ' ' (single quotes) in a sentence.

Can anyone here please let me know when to use these quotes exactly in a sentence. Am assuming that these both are the same in a sentence.

Comment: Related question on ELU: [What's the difference between using single and double quotation marks/inverted commas?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/324227/77227)

Answer (score 1):

It  completely depends on your usage. But you have to use it consistently. Commonly American prefers single quotes within double quotes, i.e.,

> "He is a 'good' man."

And British prefers vice versa, i.e.,

> 'He is a "good" man'.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in a dilemma, it's best to consult a usage guide. One of my favorites is the Purdue Online Writing Lab (a.k.a. [the Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/01/)); the OWL has an entire section devoted to [using quotation marks](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/577/).

Other commonly-used style guides in the U.S. include the [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/02/quotation-mark-uses-other-than-quotes.html) and the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch06/ch06_toc.html). The [Oxford Style Guide](http://www.eng-lang.co.uk/ogs.htm) would be a good one for British English.

These style guides often talk about "tricky" instances, such as:

> ***If I’m making a song title possessive and the song title is plural, what would I do?***
>   <sub>(see Q-and-A [here](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Quotations.html?page=1))</sub>

Not all style guides make the exact same recommendations, and variations also occur between British and American English – one of which is discussed in both Oxford and in the answer by ARYF on this question, when ARYF said, " ‘He is a "good" man’."

<sub>As a footnote, a quote within a quote within a quote is discussed [here](http://painintheenglish.com/case/5112). It's messy, but I couldn't resist.</sub>